# How to remove EXIF from image on client side? (JS or Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, exif

When a user selects an image I am trying to implement as solution to fix the EXIF orientation and then remove the EXIF so it uploads to my file server in the correct orientation without the meta data.

So far the solutions I have found is for preview files only. I am hoping if some can show me  how I could implement this solution either in Javascript or Angular?

My very basic file input is as follows:

```
  fileEvent(ev: any): void {
    let obj = ev.target.files[0];
  }
```

Thanks so much in advance,

Comment: Angular is JS...

Comment: Open the image in a canvas and save the canvas